# can't call String.isEmpty() in android

Tags: java, android

In my android application I can't use ***String.isEmpty()*** function which is situated in JDK 1.6. Android 2.1 lib doesn't have this function in java.lang.String class

I tried to input JRE System library to my project, because it has this function, but there was no effects.

How can I solve this problem and allow my application to use this function?

Comment: isEmpty is added in API Level 9. See here http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29

Comment: Odd, I haven't come across this problem. I do avoid using .isEmpty() though. I just perfer to use if(myString == null || myString.trim().size() == 0)

Comment: @Ali - ughh!!  It sounds like the code you work on is doing a bad job of specifying and checking its APIs / interface pre-conditions and post-conditions.

Comment: By the by, you can even tell JavaC to compile code to be compatible with a articular version of JRE. I've never tried it, but I wonder if it would be an easier solution in this instance. @Stephen: I've been told specifically by our software architect to always check for nulls when a value is received from an api call. Also, with user input we often has an inconsistency where the front-end can return null if a field is empty or an empty string if the user focuses the field but does not type anything. Odd I know.

Comment: @Ali - I'm not impressed with your architect.  IMO, it is a better idea to detect and deal with nulls at source rather than at every API.  Apart from that, treat unexpected nulls as bugs and let them turn into NPEs.  The trouble with explicitly testing for nulls is that your code is cluttered with pointless checks, and you may fall into the trap of "fixing" the nulls by turning them into empty strings (for example).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

> How can I solve this problem and allow my application to use this function?

You can't.

Use `String.length() == 0` instead.  It is backwards compatible all the way back to JDK 1.0 ... and with J2ME as well.

`String.equals("")` is another alternative.

---

> Are you sure that there is no way to configure Eclipse to put into a code classes from definite libraries?

Not if you want your app to run on a *real* Android device.  Java / Android platforms intentionally make it hard for you to tinker with the behaviour of the core class libraries.  For a start, you can only do it by modifying the Davlik equivalent of the bootclasspath or `rt.jar` file, and neither of these can be done within a running JVM.

That kind of tinkering has the *risk* of potentially breaking Java for other apps.  Even assuming that you can't compromise Android app separation directly (because of the process/uid separation mentioned below), malicious tweaks to the (shared) Java core classes could still potentially allow one app to interfere with, or steal information from another app.

Comment: The problem is, that I work with JSONRPC, using classes from free library http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/ and there is a function JSONRPC2Message.parse(String arg0), which use String.isEmpty() method, so when I run my app I get java.lang.noSuchMethodError exception. Are you sure that there is no way to configure Eclipse to put into a code classes from definite libraries? I mean if I want to use String class not from Android 2.1 library, but from JRE System library?

Comment: Json-simple is open source; create your own version of the library that doesn't use String.isEmpty(). That is much simpler (and safer) than trying to adapt the android runtime library.

Comment: *If they didn't it would be trivial for a rogue app to subvert security* -- I really doubt this.  Each app runs in a separate Linux process under its own uid, and Android security doesn't rely on Java package protections.  If an app modifies its own copy of `String` that has no effect on other apps.

Comment: @poolie - OK, but isn't there some sandboxing within the "JVM" that runs the app?   (I find it a bit hard to believe that it Linux-level security is the *only* protection you have against rogue apps running on your Android phone.)

Comment: @StephenC Diane Hackborn (senior Android engineer) wrote *"[we don't consider the VM to be a security barrier, and the browser
is a good reason why this is the case -- the vast majority of the browser (and the parts that tend to have security bugs) are in WebKit, which is a native C++ library.  Our platform's primary security barrier is through process/uid separation, enforced by the kernel, so native code in an app is no less secure than Java code.](http://markmail.org/message/ynstgbptjqmveh5p)"*. Anyhow, kernel protections are pretty strong, and also there are Market protections.

Comment: This is may be true.  However, if bad app could install an alternative class library or induce the user to do it, then they could subvert any security and privacy measures that are at that Java sandbox level.  Or just cause other apps to break.

Comment: @StephenC Yes, if a malicious app could write arbitrary root-owned or other-app-owned files on the system that would be a problem (to put it mildly).  But that's really not relevant to the fact Java won't let you change the implementation of `String` within a single process.

Comment: Yea, maybe.  But the bottom line is that 1) Java and Android do *try* to make it impossible for an app to change (say) String, and 2) and this *does* reduce the number of ways that rogue software can attempt to access your data, etcetera.  Removing this layer protection purely for the app programmer's convenience would be irresponsible ... IMO.

Answer (score 120):

You can use [android.text.TextUtils.isEmpty()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead. This method also checks to see if the String is null and has been available since API level 1.

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str)) {
    Log.d(TAG, "String is empty or null!");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

this method appeared in API9, so you cant use it before Android2.3

Answer (score 5):

You can use this `TextUtils.isEmpty(str)`. This is available since API level 1 or You can create you own method like below

```
public boolean isEmpty(CharSequence str) {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I think this should be the selected answer. Usint TextUtils is the best option. You dont have to create your own function to make the same.

Comment: You know you could have just written `return (str == null || str.length() == 0);`, right?

Comment: @Piovezan yes we can write this as well

Answer (score 4):

as far as I know android supports java 5 , so there is no `isEmpty();` you can use `length()` to simulate `isEmpty()`

Answer (score 1):

"".equals(yourString); also gives the same behavior like String.isEmpty();

Comment: It's actually the best solution since it also prevents a NullPointerException

Comment: This not the best solution, because you are creating a new String object each time that you want compare, while you with isEmpty are checking null and length.

Comment: @user1422434 - No you are not.  There is one and only one object representing the empty string literal for the entire VM.

Comment: But I disagree with @Lukas too.  Solutions that "prevent NPEs" are generally speaking a bad idea.  A better idea is to figure out where the unexpected `null` is coming from and fix *that problem*.  The `"".equals(yourString)` approach is only a good solution if a `null` value for `yourString` is meaningful ... and expected.

Answer (score -4):

You have to upgrade android API to level 9, or use `String.trim().length()==0` or `String.equals("")` instead, it should work for your android API level and your JDK version.

Comment: What? String ```"   "``` is not empty! Why you suggest to trim string?

Comment: @ruX `" ".trim()` will be empty!!! Do you even know that??  Do not rate down if you **DO NOT** understand my description!!!

Comment: @Eugenie Bai ```String.trim().length()==0``` and ```String.equals("")``` return different results when ```String = "  "```. Second snippet is correct